# Native UI Popover issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, lua, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to use a native `UIPopOverController` in my App. I am writing the code in `Lua`. I am planning to use `Wax` to integrate `Objective-C` and `Lua`. However, I don't know how to do this.

I'd like the popover to have a **Header** and then a list of options, sort of like the photo below.

[image: sample popover]

How to integrate `UIPopOver` in my Application using `Lua` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have wast experience with `Lua`, but I searched and find that you can Create and Assign `popover` to some View like this :

```
local popover=UIPopoverController:initWithContentViewController(viewController)
popover:setDelegate(self)
self.popover=popover
```

To assign `ContentSize` , you can use this kind of code :

```
popover:setPopoverContentSize_animated(CGSize(bounds.width, bounds.height), false)
```

You can `presentPopoverFromRect` using this line :

```
popover:presentPopoverFromRect_inView_permittedArrowDirections_animated(rootView:frame(), rootView, 0, true)
```

For your Requirement you have to just Add `Label` and `TableView` to this `PopOver`. For more details , you can always take a look at [**IosImagePicker.lua**](https://github.com/bowerhaus/BhWax/blob/master/IosImagePicker.lua).